# Android - How to show ImageView in specific cell and hide all the others

Tags: android, listview, imageview, cell

I have a radio app and when I click on a cell of a radio station, I need to show a playing icon in that cell and hide the previous ImageView.

Example, I click on **Radio 1**, it starts streaming it and shows a playing icon on the right side, like this:

[image]

then, when I click on another cell, that playing icon must hide and it must show up in the selected cell.

Here's my (incomplete) code:

```
// MARK: - QUERY STATIONS ---------------------------------------------------------------
    void queryStations(String genre) {
        Configs.showPD("Loading Stations...", Stations.this);
        final List<String> stationColors = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Configs.stationColors));

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Configs.STATIONS_CLASS_NAME);
        query.whereEqualTo(Configs.STATIONS_GENRE, genre);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    stationsArray = objects;
                    Configs.hidePD();

// CUSTOM LIST ADAPTER
class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ListAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> objects) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    // CONFIGURE CELL
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (cell == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            assert inflater != null;
            cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_station, null);
        }
        final View finalCell = cell;

        ...

        final ImageView playingIcon = finalCell.findViewById(R.id.csPlayingImage);
        playingIcon.setTag(position);
        Log.i("log-", "P.ICON TAG: " + playingIcon.getTag());
        // Play selected radio station
        sNametxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("log-", "CELL TAPPED!");
                stationIndex = position;
                playRadioStation();
                playingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // HERE'S WHERE I SHOW THE PLAYING ICON
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see by my code, the **playingIcon** gets shown correctly, but when I click on the next cell, the first playing icon doesn't obviously get hidden.

[image]

How can I make it invisible and show only the selected **playingIcon** ImageView?

Thanks so much!

Comment: is it a Recyclerview or separate layouts ?

Comment: @ManishGupta it's a ListView, no Recycler: 
                        public View getView(final int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
                            if (cell == null) {
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                assert inflater != null;
                                cell = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_station, null);
                            }

Comment: okay sir, please post entire adapter code in your question

Comment: @ManishGupta just updated my question, thanks!

Comment: Add a `boolean` value (`false` as default) to your `ParseObject` list. Then check if it's false, hide the image. Else you can show the image.

Comment: And share full code pls.

Comment: @CagriYalcin the full code is there, and I cannot add a boolean value to 'objects'

Comment: Can you share your `ParseObject` class ?

Comment: @CagriYalcin I've added the ParseQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should work:

```
class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ...
    private int stationIndex = -1;  //if needed
    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View cell, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        final ViewGroup _parent = parent;   //for access in inner class

        sNametxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("log-", "CELL TAPPED!");
                playRadioStation();
                playingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if (stationIndex >= 0) {
                    if (stationIndex != position) {
                        //get playingIcon of the the cell with position==stationIndex: 
                        _parent.getChildAt(stationIndex).findViewById(R.id.csPlayingImage).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                stationIndex = position;

            }
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside **sNametxt.setOnClickListener**:

```
if(playingIcon.getTag() == stationIndex){
   playingIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   playingIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This will only make playingIcon VISIBLE where you have clicked.
and the other one will be GONE.

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error: incomparable types: Object and int
                                    if(playingIcon.getTag() == stationIndex) - I guess I need to cast it into (int) - Anyway, it doesn't work :(

Comment: may be getTag() returns a String and stationIndex is an Int. So, try changing is to String.valueof(stationIndex)

Comment: Thanks again, I did, but now it hides the icon, i mean, if I click on a cell, it doesn't show the icon